# Problem about Postman for registering API with Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple FLASK-API which is related to authentication, I mean by simple log-in, register page. For the test by backend I use Postman, I also use MySQL for the database. When I am giving input from Postman for the register, I got an empty message. I am dropping my register route below.

```py
app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def register():

    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
        hash_password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
        email = request.form['email']

        # Check if user exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))

        cursor_email = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor_email.execute( 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = % s', (email, ))
        # Fetch one record and return result
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        print(type(user))
        # If account exists in accounts table in our database
        
        if user:
            message = 'This username already exists!'
        elif cursor_email.fetchone():
            message = 'E-mail already in usage'
        elif not email or not username:
            message = 'Please fiil out the form'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s)', (username, hash_password, email, ))
        
            mysql.connection.commit()     # Yapılan değişikleri kaydetmek ve veritabında uygulamak için gerekli olan commit fonksiyonu. Since mysql is not a auto-commit DB, it shoulde be done manually
            message = 'You have successfully registered!'

    return jsonify(message=message)
```

For the Postman page;

my HTTP method is `POST`, URL is: http://127.0.0.1:5000/register

my body in JSON format is:

```json
{

    "username": "halilcan",

    "password": "123",

    "email": "halilcan@gmail.com"



}
```

At the end on the console screen of Postman, I have this message;

```json
{

    "message": ""

}
```

Probably, my message variable at first stays as it was created.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to add but on terminal I get "127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2022 14:45:24] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -" which is good I guess because of the code 200.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are immutable so the value cannot be updated. you just need to remove the first string assignment.

```
message = ''
```

you can add a return statement inside the if block and send an error message if the first if condition is not met.

```
app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
        hash_password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
        email = request.form['email']

        # Check if user exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))

        cursor_email = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor_email.execute( 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = % s', (email, ))
        # Fetch one record and return result
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        print(type(user))
        # If account exists in accounts table in our database
        
        if user:
            message = 'This username already exists!'
        elif cursor_email.fetchone():
            message = 'E-mail already in usage'
        elif not email or not username:
            message = 'Please fiil out the form'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s)', (username, hash_password, email, ))
        
            mysql.connection.commit()     # Yapılan değişikleri kaydetmek ve veritabında uygulamak için gerekli olan commit fonksiyonu. Since mysql is not a auto-commit DB, it shoulde be done manually
            message = 'You have successfully registered!'
        return jsonify(message=message)


    return jsonify(message="some error message")
```